# Given a specific value for a variable, how do you find the predicted value of a fixed effects multivariate regression?

Tags: r, predictive-models, fixed-effects-model

I have specified the following model in R:

```r
model <- lm(yield ~ N + N^2 + P + K + S + factor(year) + factor(variety), 
            data=data)
```

As shown above, I have included fixed effects for year and variety. I want to find the predicted yield from my model, given a specific value (N = 100)for nitrogen for which I have included linear and squared terms.

I have been trying to do this with the predict function but am unsure how to do this with fixed effects and a squared term.

Comment: What is the problem with using the `predict`  method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `I(N^2)` instead of `N^2`, because otherwise `lm()` interprets `N^2` as [crossing](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula), which is not what you want here.